# Using ** instead of ^

Tags: superscripts

I am used to use `**` instead of `^`.

Is it possible to somehow define macro that would interpret `**` as `^`?

I know that I can write `**` and in the end replace it with `^` but that macro would be much more comfortable.

I have been looking for this few months ago and I discovered that you can redefine sign for superscript, but I only found that I can redefine it with only one sign but not with two.

Thank you

Comment: So what about your usage of `^` when you deal with limits? Do you use `**` as well? As in, `\sum_{i=0}**n`?

Comment: Note that `*` is something that is used in command definitions, like `\newcommand*` or `\renewcommand*`, or even in `array` column specifications: `*{<num>}{<col spec>}`...

Comment: Depending on the editor you're using, shouldn't you be able to define a macro there that changes your `**` input into `^` as you type, therefore eliminating the need to redefine any commands?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it. Don't.<sup>1</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`* \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\wagner@starstar}
\newcommand{\wagner@starstar}{%
  \@ifnextchar*{\wagner@superscript}{\wagner@asterisk}%
}
\newcommand{\wagner@superscript}[1]{^}
\mathchardef\wagner@asterisk=\mathcode`*
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`*="8000 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A*B$

$a**2$

$\begin{array}{*{2}{c}}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> It's true that several languages use `**` for denoting exponentiation (but several others use `^`). They might also have rules about the interpretation of `2**3**4`, which TeX *doesn't* have and they probably accept `2 ** 12` and this will definitely give the wrong result with TeX. Not because of the spaces, which are basically ignored in math mode, but because `2^{12}` is the correct input. You could also be prone to type things like `2**(3+5)` that would lead to disaster.

*When in Rome, do as the Romans do.*

Comment: Making `*` math active doesn't interfere with other usages of the character as shown with the `array` environment.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the `\lowercase` trick necessary here?

Comment: @zwol I avoid `\gdef` whenever possible.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: I don't understand how that bit of your code is in any way different from plain `\def*{\wagner@starstar}`.

Comment: @zwol I don't want to make `*` globally active. It could be ``\begingroup\catcode`*=\active\gdef*{\wagner@starstar}\endgroup``, of course, but, as I said, I prefer not using `\gdef` if I can avoid it.

Comment: @egreg For others coming across this, I think it would probably be beneficial if the *Don't* would be a bit more visible, in order to enforce the notion that doing it is not good practice. Just browsing over it now, it sort of reads like: *Yes you can jump out of an airplane without a parachute. Don't.* instead of *Yes you can jump out of an airplane without a parachute, however **!!!!!DON'T!!!!!*** ;)

Comment: @BMWurm I've added some reasons.

Comment: I like both the tone and content of egreg 's answer.